# Laravel login redirected you too many times

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.1, laravel-5, laravel-routing

I have been struggling with this from quiet a time now, what i am trying is to redirect all the url's hit by non-logged in users to login page and it gives me this error, which I am sure is because it is creating a loop on /login URL. authentication is checking for authorized user in login page also. however I wish the login page should be an exception when checking the auth. I may be doing something wrong which I am not able to get. here goes my code.

**routes.php**

```
Route::post('login', 'Auth\AuthController@login');
Route::get('login' , 'Auth\AuthController@showLoginForm');
Route::get('/'     , 'Auth\AuthController@showLoginForm');
```

---

**kernel.php**

```
protected $routeMiddleware = [
    'auth' => \App\Http\Middleware\Authenticate::class,
    'auth.basic' => \Illuminate\Auth\Middleware\AuthenticateWithBasicAuth::class,
    'can' => \Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\Access\Middleware\Authorize::class,
    'guest' => \App\Http\Middleware\RedirectIfAuthenticated::class,
    'throttle' => \Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\ThrottleRequests::class,
    'acl' => \App\Http\Middleware\CheckPermission::class,
];
```

---

**Authenticate class**

```
class Authenticate
{
    public function handle($request, Closure $next, $guard = null) {    
      if (Auth::guard($guard)->guest()) {
        if ($request->ajax() || $request->wantsJson()) {
            return response('Unauthorized.', 401);
        } else {
            return redirect()->guest('login');
        }
      }
    return $next($request);
    }
}
```

---

**AuthController class**

```
class AuthController extends Controller {

    use AuthenticatesAndRegistersUsers, ThrottlesLogins;
    protected $redirectTo = '/dashboard';
    protected $loginPath = '/login';
    protected $redirectPath = '/dashboard';
public function __construct(){
    $this->middleware('auth', ['except' =>'login']); 
    /* I have been trying these many things to fix this, all in loss.
    // $this->middleware('acl'); // To all methods
    // $this->middleware('acl', ['only' => ['create', 'update']]); 
    // $this->middleware('guest', ['only' => ['/login']]);
    // echo "Message"; exit;
    // $this->middleware('auth');
    // $this->middleware('auth', ['only' => ['login']]);
    // $this->middleware('auth', ['only' => ['/login']]);
    // $this->middleware('auth', ['except' => 'login']);
    // $this->middleware('guest');
    // $this->middleware('guest', ['only' => ['logout' , 'login', '/login', '/']]);
}
```

Please help me, It going all above my head, seems some sort of rocket science to me. well btw I am new to laravel and may be doing some silly thing around, apologies for that. Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why you are doing all this just to redirect every non-logged in user to login form?

i think you can just do this

**Routes.php**

```
  Route::post('login', 'Auth\AuthController@login');
  Route::get('login' , 'Auth\AuthController@showLoginForm');
  Route::get('/'     , 'Auth\AuthController@showLoginForm');

Route::group(['middleware' => 'auth'], function () {

    // any route here will only be accessible for logged in users
 });
```

and auth controller construct should be like this

**AuthController**

```
public function __construct()
    {
        $this->middleware('guest', ['except' => 'logout']);
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I will try with this in some time, I understand I was doing it all messy, however could u tell me where was i creating a loop .

Comment: I did what you have mentioned and it gives me the same error, it doesnt solve the priblem. I removed my routes and put yours and also replaced my AuthController constructor but no luck..

Comment: change this in ur auth controller Try this          `$this->middleware('auth', ['except' => 'showLoginForm']);`  i think when using a middleware in constructor you have to ,specify the method name for the expect or only , so you should not set the middleware for the Showlogin for and not login

Comment: i got it working :) but I dont know how removed $this->middleware('guest'); from my ctrl class and added all my routes inside the group you send me in routes. and it worked as I expected. Is that fine, or I ll have some loopholes in my code..

Comment: no its fine, the group i gave you does the same thing as $this->middlware , instead defining a middleware in a class define it in routes.php

Answer (score 4):

You need add route login outside Laravel group:

**routes.php**

```
Route::auth();

Route::group(['middleware' => 'auth'], function () {
  // All route your need authenticated
});
```

Aditionally, you can see yours route list using:

```
php artisan route:list
```

Comment: This should be the accepted answer. It did exactly what I needed to, clean and simple, like laravel meant it to be.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is with your routes.

When I enter and I am not logged out you send me to login(get) route. And as you are specifying the middleware in the construct function in the AuthController, every time a method of the AuthController is called, construct function is called again and sends you back at login.. and it repeats indefinitely.

Comment: so how can i fix this, I know I am doing something wrong ?

Answer (score 1):

like @mkmnstr say

> The problem is with your routes.
>   When I enter and I am not logged out you send me to login(get) route. And as you are specifying the middleware in the construct function in the AuthController, every time a method of the AuthController is called, construct function is called again and sends you back at login.. and it repeats indefinitely.

to fix that u should add

```
Auth::logout();
```

Here

```
...
} else {
  Auth::logout(); // user must logout before redirect them
  return redirect()->guest('login');
}
...
```

Answer (score 0):

If your working with custom middleware you must follow it's all rules 
in my case, I have to define a custom route class in the web middleware group.
In the world of copy-paste sometime we make mistakes.

**Middleware** :

```
 public function handle($request, Closure $next)
    {

        if(!isset(session('user'))){
            return redirect('login');
        }

        return $next($request);
    }
}
```

**My Mistake in Kernel.php** 

if custom middleware class present in web $middlewareGroups will check condition 2 times so it will give error as: **redirected you too many times**

```
protected $middlewareGroups = [
        'web' => [ 
                 \App\Http\Middleware\webUser::class, //Remove
        ],

protected $routeMiddleware = [ 
      'webUser'=> \App\Http\Middleware\webUser::class //Keepit  
]
```

Answer (score 0):

I had same problem after creating my own route service provider. The problem was that when I tried to login, in first time login page showed and after entering credentials I encountered "redirected too many times" and redirected to my admin dashboard and login route!
the solution was: adding middleware "web" into my routes:

```
Route::middleware('web')->group(base_path('Admin/routes.php'));
```